# JSON response for REST API post for collections

Tags: json, api, rest

I have found very little detail about best practices when responding to PUT or POST commands with a REST API.

Assume the example is that the API is for a list of movies in a movie store and has the following:

- GET api/Movies
- GET api/Movies/{id}
- PUT api/Movies/
- PUT api/Movies/{id}
- POST api/Movies/
- POST api/Movies/{id}

Where you can PUT or POST either single or collections. I included both because I do not want to get into a discussion about PUT vs. POST, and would like an answer on best practices, particularly in response to errors.

If working on a single item I can return HTTP status codes and a response easily, but what should be done when handling POST and PUT of collections, especially in a non-idempotent method?

My thought for returning a package would be as follows:

```
{
   "version": "1.0"
   "status": 200,
   "errors": [
      // List of object id's, and errors
   ]
   "data": [
      // List of movies POSTed or PUT
   ]
}
```

With the errors being generated for each specific ID that failed, but I'm not sure it passes the smell test in regards to overall status and HttpStatus. Should I return another status if a portion of the collection fails or a single entity fails?

Comment: The status code should be used to represent status of the transport. Server configuration issues and unhandled exceptions usually result in a code 500. Resource not found, unauthorized access etc. etc. usually result in code 4xx's. The code 200 indicates that the server validated the request and sent a valid response. The determination of a valid payload for a valid response,200,  is up to the semantics of your api.

Comment: I am a fan of using HTTP 303 to redirect successful POST/PUT requests. I would never include an error payload in an HTTP 200, unless such an error did not prevent the request from completing: that is, the new resource was created (POST) or updated (PUT), but with additional conditions resulting in a non-fatal error.

Comment: @lrb - This is what I have assumed with my payload response; transport succeeded errors in processing. I have not seen detailed information on standards concerning this with collections of responses, and the brief information on different sites is contradictory at best. That said, many APIs use status code for processing as well (twitter, for example).

Comment: @Palpatim - I am referring specifically to a collection (several of) POST/PUT items. Are you saying you would return an error code for the entire collection and not process any of the items if one is defunct? On an idempotent action, I would think 1 item should not hold up the entire send... of course, I'm not sure on that, hence my question.

Comment: Evert's answer explains my position nicely. If the request is truly idempotent, then the entirety of the request must succeed or fail, and an error is an expected response if one element of the request fails. Think of a transaction model, such as would be implemented in DBMS--if one record update fails, the entire transaction must be rolled back.

Comment: @Palpatim - Thanks, after looking at more resources based on your (and Evert's) response I believe I agree with this method now and have already implemented it; simply sticking with idempotent requests only is likely the most reasonable solution in the case of collections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally in REST a operation needs to completely succeed or completely fail. Operations like this should be atomic and idempotent.

So what you're asking is simply outside of what REST can do for you. From the horse's mouth:

> "If you find yourself in need of a batch operation, then most likely you just haven’t defined enough resources."

http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-743

So what does that quote mean? It doesn't mean that you can't have a resource representing the same data as several other resources (e.g.: your collection), but if you are using `PUT` to update it, you are still 100% replacing its contents. Not partially.

Comment: It seems you have a different interpretation than I would have given; even if I had given two separate answers. I would consider this a simple bulk operation as it does not meet the criteria I imagine a batch operation does. It does not (a) process different payload types in one operation; or (b) consist of multiple requests to complete a single transaction. So your comment: "outside of what REST can do for you" confuses, as the nature of current REST API's show collection actions, and attempted standards (JSONapi, OData, etc.) list operations for bulk.

Comment: I have accepted this answer based on the comments referring to Atomicity. My collection based action will not be modifying singular items and will simply be atomic and idempotent. In any instance where I would not be doing full replacements of data, I plan on still maintaining atomicity and failing the transaction with a returned error code and list of errors; anyways. Thanks for the response, Evert.

Comment: As to your point about JSONapi and OData, if they are providing bulk operations, those operations themselves are probably not RESTful. It doesn't mean it's not a valid api design, or valid use of HTTP... it's just not REST.

Comment: Do you have any citation for how a bulk operation violates the architectural constraints and causes an API not to be RESTful? I'm truly interested in the reasoning. The original post highlighted by yourself does not state this, nor does the quote. If I GET Api/Movies and return a collection of movies, and then simply PUT Api/Movies with that same collection (albeit modified), how does that violate RESTful architecture if the transaction was stateless and atomic?

Comment: Hi Kaylus, if you are using `PUT` and you are fully replacing the existing collection, then that's still RESTful. I'm just talking about 'bulk operations', but to be fair, I don't know how they are implemented in JSONapi/OData. So I was 100% inferring.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That is what I was getting at, I figured it was simply the terminology I was using which was based on how some of the key APIs term it and may not have, necessarily, been correct. Thanks for the clarification and answer!